# DirectX SDK folder missing folders

Tags: c++, file, directx

My application requires   Microsoft DirectX June (2010)/lib/x86  however the only things that appears when opening the folder are  DirectX Utility folders.

My theory is that the download must have been updated or something because when I downloaded Detours again the files were different.

Anyone know how to get the lib file?

Comment: Download the SDK from microsoft

Comment: I have. I got it from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=6812

Answer (score 0):

The legacy DirectX SDK is available from download from the Microsoft Downloads site. The self-extracting EXE itself is now SHA-256 signed, but the content is unchanged from the June 2010 release.

- http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=226640

The legacy DirectSetup REDIST image is available here:

- http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=159853
- http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=194352

The self-extracting EXE, DSETUP EXEs/DLLs, and CABS are now SHA-256 signed, but the content is unchanged from the April 2011 refresh.

Keep in mind there are numerous known issues with these old bits. In particular, your original report sounds like you may have hit this issue:

- https://walbourn.github.io/known-issue-directx-sdk-june-2010-setup-and-the-s1023-error/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows/win32/s1023-error-when-you-install-directx-sdk

Finally, if you are trying to use the legacy DirectX SDK with VS 2012 or later, the integration instructions are different. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009

**Note that you really shouldn't need to use the legacy DirectX SDK at all.**

- The Windows SDK already includes the include headers and link libraries for d3d9.lib, d3d10.lib, d3d11.lib, dxgi.lib, dxguid.lib, etc. See https://walbourn.github.io/directx-sdks-of-a-certain-age/
- If you need d3dx9, d3dx10, or d3dx11, you should use this [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) instead which provides the headers, link libraries, and a simple side-by-side REDIST for those DLLs. They are also SHA-256 signed. See https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/
- If you need XAudio2 for Windows 7, then use this [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.XAudio2.Redist/) instead. See https://aka.ms/xaudio2redist
- If you need dxerr.lib, build it yourself. See https://walbourn.github.io/wheres-dxerr-lib/
- If you use the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies, use SharpDX or SlimDX instead. https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-net/

> The only scenarios where you still have to use the legacy DirectX SDK are (a) to target Windows XP or (b) to use XACT.